# Getting an error using restassured and testng. java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class org.hamcrest.Matcher

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Hi I've been using these Json paths in the past but for some reason I've encountered an issue I can't seem to solve. I think it is something to do with my response having an array? Now when I tried yesterday I got a strange response which I'm no longer getting I'm now getting an error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast
> to class org.hamcrest.Matcher (java.util.ArrayList is in module
> java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.hamcrest.Matcher is in unnamed
> module of loader 'app')

```
    package skySportsPages;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;

public class test extends enablers {


    @Test
    public void GetArticlesJson() {

        JsonPath expectedJson = new JsonPath(new File("src/test/java/jsonFiles/articles.json"));

        given().
                when().
                get(allArticles).
                then().
                assertThat().
                contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                and().
                body("", hasItem(expectedJson.get("")));


    }

}
```

POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>skysport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>

        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>


    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured-common</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Response I should get.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "createdAt": "2020-10-27T19:10:01.232Z",
    "title": "title 1",
    "sensitive": false,
    "topics": [
      "business",
      "politics",
      "technology"
    ],
    "image": null,
    "priority": 89
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "createdAt": "2020-10-28T07:45:21.526Z",
    "title": "title 2",
    "sensitive": true,
    "topics": [],
    "image": {
      "url": "https://imgur.com",
      "fileType": ".jpg"
    },
    "priority": 45
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "createdAt": "2020-10-27T13:09:32.347Z",
    "title": "£31 million pounds shortfall in economy",
    "sensitive": false,
    "topics": [],
    "image": {
      "url": "https://imgur.com",
      "fileType": ".svg"
    },
    "priority": 25
  },
  {
    "id": "4656364867443",
    "createdAt": "2020-10-27T17:03:33.158Z",
    "title": "title 4",
    "sensitive": true,
    "topics": [
      "USA"
    ],
    "image": {},
    "priority": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "createdAt": "2020-10-28T02:46:16.766Z",
    "title": "title 5",
    "sensitive": false,
    "topics": [],
    "image": {},
    "priority": 56
  }
]
```

Comment: what is `allArticles` ?

Comment: Just my endpoint that I bring in from the enablers that brings back the Json response that I've added into the question.

Comment: I've actually resolved my issue now I was using older versions of java so ive no updated it restarted my project and im now getting the results I need.